# Invalid JSON Generated from asp.net Webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

Can any one guide, what is wrong with below generated JSON code which are generated thru asp.net web service's methods.

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
Error: Invalid JSON: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"id:" '1',"title:" 'Event1',"start:"  1310236200,"end:" 1310236200,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'Event1'},{"id:" '3',"title:" 'Event2',"start:"  1309804200,"end:" 1309804200,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'Event2'},{"id:" '4',"title:" 'Event5',"start:"  1311705000,"end:" 1311705000,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'Event5'},{"id:" '5',"title:" 'Event3',"start:"  1309006800,"end:" 1309006800,"allDay:"false,"description:" 'Event3'},{"id:" '6',"title:" 'Event4',"start:"  1310495400,"end:" 1310495400,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'Event4'},{"id:" '7',"title:" 'Time Event1',"start:"  1312144200,"end:" 1312174800,"allDay:"false,"description:" 'Time Event1'},{"id:" '8',"title:" 'save1',"start:"  1312309800,"end:" 1312309800,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'save1111'},{"id:" '9',"title:" 'today',"start:"  1311273000,"end:" 1311273000,"allDay:"true,"description:" 'today'}]</string>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is concluded in wrong request to service. Please see working code:

Web-service code:

```
namespace Test.Service
{
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [ToolboxItem(false)]
  [ScriptService]
  public class WebService1 : WebService
  {
    [WebMethod]
    public object HelloWorld()
    {
      // ! return anonymous object. It cannot be serialized to xml and orients solely to json-request.
      return new { value = 12345, name = "John" };
    }
  }
}
```

1. getting data via jquery

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "Service/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
           data: "{}",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d.value);
             alert(data.d.name);
           }
       });
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. getting data via ASP.NET AJAX

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="_scriptManager" runat="server">
     <Services>
       <asp:ServiceReference Path="Service/WebService1.asmx" />
     </Services>
   </asp:ScriptManager>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function () {
       Test.Service.WebService1.HelloWorld(OnComplete);

       function OnComplete(result) {
         alert(result.value);
         alert(result.name);
       }
     }  
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Trick question?

Because that's XML, not JSON.

hence the error

Comment: thts true. But how can call webservice for JSON in asp.net ?

Comment: What's really odd for me is that my XmlHttpRequest is returning XML and being successfully parsed via JSON.parse() with Google Chrome, but on the Android stock browser (which I'm led to believe also runs on WebKit) I get an "unexpected token ILLEGAL" error. 

It's for that reason I assumed that if it worked on my developer machine browser it would work on Android browser too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your request specifies the "`application/xml`" or "`text/xml`" content type, make sure you specify the "`application/json`" content type instead.

You can verify this using a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or your web browser's development tools (e.g. Firebug, Chrome dev tools).

If you show us the JavaScript code we can possibly find something, otherwise make sure you're using [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or specifying "`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`" if you're using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (with the actual charset you need).